# How modify existing Outlook .msg file without saving to Outlook inbox using Interop

Tags: c#, .net, email, outlook, office-interop

I created the following class to open an existing Outlook .msg file on disc (the 'template'), change some properties, add attachments and save it back to disc in another location. However, when I open Outlook, a new file appears in my inbox in addition to the save location! I don't want to save to any Outlook folders at all, just modify the file on disk. How do I prevent it from saving to my inbox?

```
public class OutlookMailManager
{
    public const string OutlookExtn = ".msg";

    public void GenerateMail(string toAddress, string fromAddress, string templateFile, string outputFile, string attachmentFile)
    {
        MailItem item = OpenMessage(templateFile);
        item.To = toAddress;
        item.SentOnBehalfOfName = fromAddress;
        item.Attachments.Add(attachmentFile);
        SaveMessage(outputFile, item);
    }

    private MailItem OpenMessage(string fileName)
    {
        var app = new Application();
        return (MailItem)app.Session.OpenSharedItem(fileName);
    }

    private void SaveMessage(string fileName, MailItem item)
    {
        fileName = Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, OutlookExtn);
        item.SaveAs(fileName, OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) and [OpenIMsgOnIStg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815715.aspx) function or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language, I am its author) - create an instance of the [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) object, call RDOSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile (returns an instance of the [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) object), modify it, call `RDOMail.Save` or `RDOMail.SaveAs`.